Strange asymmetric saturation with ADA4099
Good afternoon — my first question here, I hope I follow all the rules...
So, I am trying to design a series of filters with op-amps that have a shutdown pin, using only 0 ­→ 3.3V supply and an analog "ground" at 1.65 V. I need a rail-to-rail component, given the small analog range, and my first selection has been the ADA4099. But I have a puzzling result that I would like to understand fully.
I was able to reduce the problem to this simple circuit (I hope you can download the .asc LTspice file here) :

See the positive saturation in the lower circuit? I initially dismissed that as a problem of the model (the buffer works!), but then the physical circuit is doing exactly the same.
I suspect that this is some kind of protection kicking in, but I'd like to understand what's happening. In principle, the input range is the full supply voltage, and no voltage is outside the power supply.
Has anybody any explanation for this behavior? What should I have checked in the datasheet to expect it?

These "over the top" devices draw significant current when you have a high enough input CM voltage to operate in that mode. The relevant datasheet section is on Page 21:

OVER-THE-TOP OPERATION CONSIDERATIONS
When the ADA4099-1 and ADA4099-2
input common-modes are biased near or >+VS supply, the amplifiers
operate in the Over-TheTop configuration. The differential input pair
that controls amplifier operation is the common base pair, Q3 to Q6
(see Figure 55). Input bias currents change from <±4 nA in normal
operation to approximately 82.5 μA in Over-The-Top operation when the
input stage transitions from common emitter to common base. The
OverThe-Top input bias currents are well matched, and the associated
offset is typically <250 nA. Ensure that the impedance connected to
the inverting and noninverting inputs is well matched to avoid any
input bias current induced voltage offsets.

Effectively, the input bias current increases by about 20,000:1 since the input stage is now being powered from the input signal.
You can see where the typical transition takes place here:

.. between 3 and 4 volts in, with a 5V supply, so with a 3.3V supply we'd expect more like 1.8V with a 3.3V supply.
Conventional RRIO op-amps contain effectively two front ends and there is a transition where there is a (usually) gentle shift in Vos. Whichever way you do it, RR inputs are not 100% 'clean'.

Thank you very much. Two perfectly good answer, I'll mark accepted the first one.

The problem lies in the input stage of that op-amp. When the input signal is below Vcc - 1.5 volts, the input bias current is quite low and decent but, when the input signal rises to above 1.5 volts below Vcc, the bias current dramatically rises about 100,000 times. See the data sheet you linked: -

And, because you have a 10 kΩ input resistor, this rapidly rising bias current causes the anomaly.

Thank you very much. Two perfectly good answer, I'll mark accepted the first one ;-) --- sorry (I'd like to mark both, but...)
